# SIGSEGV When Accessing Link Parser Through JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

The server I'm trying to set this up on has Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5.4 64-bit. We've compiled and installed Link Parser 4.6.7 (64-bit) as well as both JDK5 and JDK6 64-bit.

When calling on the library, this is the error returned:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002aaaaefeb180, pid=24955, tid=1103116608
>
> JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
>
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> Problematic frame:
>
> C  [liblink-grammar.so.4+0xa180]  linkage_get_num_words+0x0

This hasn't been encountered with the same Java code running on Windows, OS X, and other Linux distributions.

Also, Link Parser works fine through the provided executables (link-parser), so it doesn't appear to be a problem with compiling and installing the package.

Comment: At what point does this occur? During initialization? After you invoke a JNI method? Which method? What does your calling Java code look like?  You really haven't provided anywhere near enough information.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a quirk with the data we were using, which on this new machine was slightly different. Pipe characters were causing the segfault, which we couldn't recreate in any other environment.

We removed the offending characters and ran it without issue and notified the developer.